# Where to find the snippets in Eclipse Juno / Kepler Classic?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In previous versions of Eclipse (like Helios), the snippets where in

Window > Show View > General > Snippets.

Now it seems that I can't find them anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are still under

**Window > Show View > General > Snippets.**

but if you can't see them, you **need to install the "Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools".**

Check the screen below:

[image]